# Terraform: how do I tell a Windows EC2 instance to use the entire disk? (PowerShell in userdata)

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, terraform

I have a Windows and a Linux AWS instance that are started in a near-identical way:

```
resource "aws_instance" "test-instance" {
  key_name = var.key_name
  subnet_id = var.subnet_id
  ami = data.aws_ami.image.id
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  security_groups = var.security_groups
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  disable_api_termination = "false"
  monitoring = "false"
  tags = {
    Name = "test-instance-linux-${local.timestamp}"
  }
  root_block_device {
    volume_size = var.root_volume_size
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags.Name
    ]
  }
}
```

- `test-instance-linux-${local.timestamp}` for the Linux instance
- `test-instance-windows-${local.timestamp}` for the Windows instance
- `var.root_volume_size` equals `'200'` (GiB).

When I use this, then I see in the AWS console that both instances, Windows and Linux, have a 200 GiB volume as device `/dev/sda1`. Great.

However, while the Linux instance uses the entire 200 GiB, on Windows I only have 30 GiB available, which is most likely the size of the original `Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base-...` AMI I started from (customized with Packer).

How do I tell the Windows instance to use the entire disk?

*Already tried*

I added this to the `resource "aws_instance" "test-instance"`:

```
user_data = file("userdata.txt")
```

And this is in `userdata.txt`:

```
<powershell>
# Variable specifying the drive you want to extend
$drive_letter = "C"

# Script to get the partition sizes and then resize the volume
$size = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $drive_letter)
Resize-Partition -DriveLetter $drive_letter -Size $size.SizeMax
</powershell>
```

(PowerShell code found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/extend-a-basic-volume)

However, actual free disk space is ~7.7 GiB (of 30), instead of expected ~177.7 GiB.

Disk info:

```
PS C:\Users\foobar> Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter "C" 

    SizeMin      SizeMax 
    -------      ------- 
23978442752 214746267648 

PS C:\Users\foobar> Get-Disk      

Number Friendly Name                                                                                            Serial Number                    HealthStatus         OperationalStatus      Total Size Partition  
                                                                                                                                                                                                        Style      
------ -------------                                                                                            -------------                    ------------         -----------------      ---------- ---------- 
0      NVMe Amazon Elastic B                                                                                    vol004fab740dda0c847_00000001.   Healthy              Online                     200 GB MBR        

PS C:\Users\foobar> Get-Partition 

   DiskPath: \\?\scsi#disk&ven_nvme&prod_amazon_elastic_b#4&26a12046&0&000000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b} 

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                                                                      Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                                                                      ---- ----
1                C           1048576                                                                                    30 GB IFS

PS C:\Users\foobar> Get-Volume

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining  Size 
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------  ----
C                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                       7.7 GB 30 GB
```

It appears as if Terraform didn't run the PowerShell script?

When I manually log in over SSH and I manually run the PowerShell script, then it works, so I know that the script itself is correct.

```
PS C:\Users\ansible> Resize-Partition -DriveLetter 'C' -Size '214746267648' 

PS C:\Users\ansible> Get-Partition 

   DiskPath: \\?\scsi#disk&ven_nvme&prod_amazon_elastic_b#4&26a12046&0&000000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b} 

PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                                                                      Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                                                                      ---- ----
1                C           1048576                                                                                   200 GB IFS

PS C:\Users\foobar> Get-Volume

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining   Size 
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------   ----
C                        NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    177.69 GB 200 GB
```

So how do I make sure that Terraform actually tells the Windows instance to execute that PowerShell script?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a PowerShell script and modifying the size after creation/boot it would be cleaner to customise the AMI and increase the boot volume size directly.

The steps to do that are explained in he [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html) but it boils down to spinning up an instance, doing the necessary modifications, creating a snapshot and turning this into a new AMI.

Comment: To clarify: where should the PowerShell script `resize.ps1` physically reside? (A) On the local Linux machine that runs Terraform (B) on the remote Windows instance on AWS.

Comment: Both. You create it locally and then you supply it via `user_data` to be copied to the remote machine where it's made accessible at the time of creation to be executed by the provisioner. See ["Passing data into virtual machines and other compute resources"](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/syntax.html#passing-data-into-virtual-machines-and-other-compute-resources).

Comment: Thank you. Your comment of copying `resize.ps1` to the remote machine got me thinking. The Terraform documentation describes provisioning as a last resort so I will take a different approach. I'm customizing the AMI with Packer, using Ansible as provisioner. With `ansible.windows.win_copy` I'll copy `resize.ps1` into the AMI, and with `community.windows.win_scheduled_task` I'll run the script at boot - see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_scheduled_task_module.html.

Comment: It does not _hurt_ if the script is run on every boot. Reboots are not expected, we'd much rather create a new AMI (these are ephemeral Jenkins nodes).

Comment: Yes indeed using `provisioner` should be the last resort, if you're able to customise the AMI then I'd recommend doing that. But if you're customising the AMI anyway then I'd increase the boot volume size directly rather than using the PowerShell resize "hack".

Comment: Well guess what, out of the hundreds if not thousands of Ansible modules, there's one called `community.windows.win_partition`, which does exactly what it says on the tin!

Comment: I found this conversation very productive. My problem was solved, which was my goal. Your initial answer wasn't a direct solution, but our conversation that followed from it, lead me on the right path. So if you want some SO points, then I propose that you turn your "customize the AMI" comment into an answer, and I'll upvote&accept that. OK for you?